# Align equations with conditions

Tags: spacing, equations, align

I am using the following equation with boundary conditions,

[image]

I would like to position the equation centrally aligned and would like to keep the boundary condition to the right. But the equation is a little bit centre-left aligned and boundary conditions are not exactly at right. Would anyone suggest a better alignment for this case? Here is the snippet, if anyone likes to help!

```
\subsubsection{Outflow}
For the outflow boundary condition, the pressure is specified as a Dirichlet boundary condition, assigned with free-stream pressure and the density $\rho$ and the velocity $\vec{u}$ are specified as a Neumann boundary condition,
\begin{align}
p &= p_\infty & \text{ on }  \Gamma_{out} \\
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \hat{n}} &= 0  & \text{ on }  \Gamma_{out} \\ 
\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial \hat{n}} &= 0  & \text{ on }  \Gamma_{out}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would't use center alignment for the three equations: either you align them at the equals sign or left align them because of the side conditions. I wouldn't put the conditions too far from the equations, either: the conditions are part of the equations, after all. A `\quad` or `\qquad` seems sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Outflow}
For the outflow boundary condition, the pressure is specified as a Dirichlet boundary 
condition, assigned with free-stream pressure and the density $\rho$ and the velocity 
$\vec{u}$ are specified as a Neumann boundary condition,
\begin{alignat}{2}
&p = p_\infty\qquad                            && \text{on $\Gamma_{\mathrm{out}}$} \\
&\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\hat{n}} = 0      && \text{on $\Gamma_{\mathrm{out}}$} \\
&\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial \hat{n}} = 0 && \text{on $\Gamma_{\mathrm{out}}$}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want alignment on the equals signs, just change the position of the first `&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Outflow}
For the outflow boundary condition, the pressure is specified as a Dirichlet boundary
condition, assigned with free-stream pressure and the density $\rho$ and the velocity
$\vec{u}$ are specified as a Neumann boundary condition,
\begin{alignat}{2}
p &= p_\infty\qquad                            && \text{on $\Gamma_{\mathrm{out}}$} \\
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\hat{n}} &= 0      && \text{on $\Gamma_{\mathrm{out}}$} \\
\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial \hat{n}} &= 0 && \text{on $\Gamma_{\mathrm{out}}$}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My personal preference goes to the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for the `\mathrm` add on the subscripts. Would use them for all subscripts

Answer (score 4):

To achieve your stated objective of placing the main equations in the middle of the textbock, you could augment your current system of equations with an additional, *invisible* column *to the left* of the main equations, and have new new column contain `\text{on $\Gamma_{out}$` as well. The text can be made invisible by encasing it in a `\phantom` statement.

Note that it's not necessary to provide the invisible stuff in all three rows -- providing it once, e.g., in the first row, suffices to achieve the desired effect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Gout{\Gamma_{\!\textit{out}}} % occurs repeatedly
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Outflow}
For the outflow boundary condition, the pressure is specified as a Dirichlet boundary 
condition, assigned with free-stream pressure and the density $\rho$ and the velocity 
$\vec{u}$ are specified as a Neumann boundary condition,
\begin{align}
&\phantom{\text{on $\Gout$}} & p &= p_\infty & \text{on $\Gout$} \\
&& \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial \hat{n}} &= 0  & \text{on $\Gout$} \\ 
&& \frac{\partial\vec{u}}{\partial\hat{n}} &= 0  & \text{on $\Gout$}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```